# How can I easily find out if a Python class accepts the with keyword?

Tags: python

The only time I ever use the `with` keyword is when reading and writing files, mostly because that's the only case I actually know that I can use it. I can imagine there are numerous instances where I preferably could have used `with`, but didn't know a class or method accepted it.

So, how do I detect instances where the `with` keyword can be used?

Comment: Read the source! If it defines `__exit__` and `__enter__` method it supports with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context managers all have `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods, so checking to see if those attributes exist and that they have `__call__` attributes will work almost all the time.

But yeah, read the code and/or documentation for the class first.